# display notification no longer working in El Capitan

Tags: applescript, zsh, osx-elcapitan, osascript, notificationcenter

I have this function in my `.zshrc` for when I want to create a notification from a script in my shell:

```
notify() { osascript -e 'display notification "${*}"' }
```

The function just runs that one tiny line of applescript to create a notification with whatever arguments are passed to it that way I can do things like this:

```
transmission SOMEFILETODOWNLOAD && notify Torrent complete
```

The problem is that ever since I upgraded to El Capitan, this function no longer works. It fails silently and creates no notification.

I ran the applescript part alone in the script editor utility and it worked fine, so I know `display notification` isn't deprecated. I'm guessing it has something to do with running it from the command line or zsh specifically.

I can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: This is not related to silently failing (cannot reproduce), but the function definition is clearly flawed. It will always print `*`, because you are always sending `display notification "${*}"` literally to `osascript`.

Comment: Thanks, I can fix that. I'm still not getting any output however, even when I run it directly in the shell with something like this: `osascript -e 'display notification "Test"'`

Comment: Try (1) log out and back in; (2) reboot. Sometimes this fixes Notification Center related problems.

Comment: Tried that several times. No luck.

Comment: No idea. Did you upgrade from Yosemite or performed a clean install? I have no problem on my clean install.

Comment: I did a clean install.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to permit Terminal to control your system by adding it to the list in

System Preferences > Privacy > Accessibility > 
"Allow the apps below to control your computer"